# Laravel 9 - Constrain the data returned into index after search generated

Tags: laravel, methods, laravel-query-builder

I have created a custom index blade which return orders.

When loaded the data are filtered with the status of the order. status_id is equal to 2.

```
if($user_role_id == 5){
                $orders->whereJsonContains('order_items.laboratory_id', ['1']);
                $orders->whereIn('order_items.status_id', [2]);
                $orders->whereNull('order_items.deleted_at');
            } else if($user_role_id == 6){
                $orders->whereJsonContains('order_items.laboratory_id', ['2']);
                $orders->whereIn('order_items.status_id', [2]);
                $orders->where('order_items.deleted_at', '=', NULL);
            } else if ...
```

The data are loaded and displayed correctly.

[image]

When I search a term inside the returned rows and columns,

[image]

the data are returned accordingly (means only the order having the search term into one or several columns are returned)

[image]

but also the order with a status_id different of 2. You can see in the above picture the left dropdown in black is in fact an order with a status_id equal to 3 (which mean order processed).

I have tried several things :

```
...
$orders  = $orders->whereIn('order_items.status_id', [2])->paginate(10);
...
```

```
$orders->where('order_items.status_id', [2]);
```

Would appreciate your expertise. Thanks.

**Method**

```
    /**
     * Display a listing of the orders filtered with status_id == 2
     *
     * @param  \App\Http\Requests  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function orderManagement(Request $request)
    {
        $staffs = $this->getStaffs();
        $laboratory_staffs = $this->getLaboratorystaffs();
        $status_orders = $this->getStatusorders();
        $user_role_id = $this->getUserRoleId();

        $term = $request->search_term;

        $orders = DB::table('order_items');
        $orders->leftJoin('order_status','order_items.status_id', '=', 'order_status.id');
        $orders->leftJoin('users AS users_a','order_items.orderer_id', '=', 'users_a.id');
        $orders->leftJoin('users AS users_b','order_items.customer_id', '=', 'users_b.id');
        $orders->leftJoin('users AS users_c','order_items.owner_id', '=', 'users_c.id');
        $orders->leftJoin('delivery_slots', 'order_items.delivery_slot_id', '=', 'delivery_slots.id');
        $orders->leftJoin('products', 'order_items.product_id', '=', 'products.id');
        $orders->leftJoin('product_categories', 'order_items.product_category_id', '=', 'product_categories.id');
        $orders->leftJoin('cake_servings','order_items.cake_serving_id', '=', 'cake_servings.id');
        $orders->leftJoin('tart_servings','order_items.tart_serving_id', '=', 'tart_servings.id');
        $orders->leftJoin('thin_tart_servings','order_items.thin_tart_serving_id', '=', 'thin_tart_servings.id');
        $orders->leftJoin('party_loaf_servings','order_items.party_loaf_serving_id', '=', 'party_loaf_servings.id');
        $orders->leftJoin('party_loaf_weights','order_items.party_loaf_weight_id', '=', 'party_loaf_weights.id');
        $orders->leftJoin('party_loaf_assortment_one','order_items.party_loaf_assortment_one_id', '=', 'party_loaf_assortment_one.id');
        $orders->leftJoin('party_loaf_assortment_two','order_items.party_loaf_assortment_two_id', '=', 'party_loaf_assortment_two.id');
        $orders->leftJoin('party_loaf_assortment_three','order_items.party_loaf_assortment_three_id', '=', 'party_loaf_assortment_three.id');
        $orders->leftJoin('party_loaf_assortment_four','order_items.party_loaf_assortment_four_id', '=', 'party_loaf_assortment_four.id');
        $orders->leftJoin('savoury_canapes_variants','order_items.savoury_canapes_variant_id', '=', 'savoury_canapes_variants.id');
        $orders->leftJoin('savoury_mini_croissants_variants','order_items.savoury_mini_croissants_variant_id', '=', 'savoury_mini_croissants_variants.id');
        $orders->leftJoin('savoury_mini_delices_variants','order_items.savoury_mini_delices_variant_id', '=', 'savoury_mini_delices_variants.id');
        $orders->leftJoin('savoury_mini_puffs_variants','order_items.savoury_mini_puffs_variant_id', '=', 'savoury_mini_puffs_variants.id');
        $orders->leftJoin('savoury_mini_ramequins_variants','order_items.savoury_mini_ramequins_variant_id', '=', 'savoury_mini_ramequins_variants.id');
        $orders->leftJoin('savoury_mini_vols_au_vent_variants','order_items.savoury_mini_vols_au_vent_variant_id', '=', 'savoury_mini_vols_au_vent_variants.id');
        $orders->leftJoin('savoury_petit_pain_bouchee_variants','order_items.savoury_petit_pain_bouchee_variant_id', '=', 'savoury_petit_pain_bouchee_variants.id');
        $orders->leftJoin('sweet_sweets','sweet_sweet_id', '=', 'sweet_sweets.id');
        $orders->leftJoin('ice_cream_small_pots_flavors','ice_cream_small_pots_flavor_id', '=', 'ice_cream_small_pots_flavors.id');
        $orders->leftJoin('ice_cream_pots_flavors','ice_cream_pots_flavor_id', '=', 'ice_cream_pots_flavors.id');
        $orders->leftJoin('ice_cream_frozen_fruits','ice_cream_frozen_fruit_id', '=', 'ice_cream_frozen_fruits.id');
        $orders->leftJoin('yul_log_christmas_servings','yul_log_christmas_serving_id', '=', 'yul_log_christmas_servings.id');
        $orders->leftJoin('yul_log_christmas_flavor','yul_log_christmas_flavor_id', '=', 'yul_log_christmas_flavor.id');
        $orders->leftJoin('yul_log_frozen_liters','yul_log_frozen_liter_id', '=', 'yul_log_frozen_liters.id');
        $orders->leftJoin('yul_log_frozen_flavor_one','yul_log_frozen_flavor_one_id', '=', 'yul_log_frozen_flavor_one.id');
        $orders->leftJoin('yul_log_frozen_flavor_two','yul_log_frozen_flavor_two_id', '=', 'yul_log_frozen_flavor_two.id');
        $orders->leftJoin('yul_log_frozen_flavor_three','yul_log_frozen_flavor_three_id', '=', 'yul_log_frozen_flavor_three.id');
        $orders->select(
            'order_items.id as id',
            'order_items.product_category_id as product_category_id',
            'product_categories.name as product_category_name',
            'order_items.order_id as order_id',
            'order_items.status_id as status_id',
            'order_status.status_order as status_order',
            'order_items.orderer_id as orderer_id',
            'order_items.customer_id as customer_id',
            'users_a.name as orderer_name',
            'users_b.name as customer_name',
            'users_b.mobile AS customer_mobile',
            'order_items.owner_id as owner_id',
            'users_c.name as owner_name',
            'order_items.delivery_date as delivery_date',
            'delivery_slots.delivery_slot as delivery_time',
            'products.id as product_id',
            'products.name as product_name',
            'order_items.quantity as quantity',
            'on_tray as on_tray',
            'cut_bread as cut_bread',
            'cake_servings.servings as cake_serving',
            'tart_servings.servings as tart_serving',
            'thin_tart_servings.servings as thin_tart_serving',
            'party_loaf_servings.servings as party_loaf_serving',
            'party_loaf_weights.weight as party_loaf_weight',
            'party_loaf_assortment_one.assortment as party_loaf_assortment_one',
            'party_loaf_assortment_two.assortment as party_loaf_assortment_two',
            'party_loaf_assortment_three.assortment as party_loaf_assortment_three',
            'party_loaf_assortment_four.assortment as party_loaf_assortment_four',
            'savoury_canapes_variants.variant as canape_variant',
            'savoury_mini_delices_variants.variant as mini_delice_variant',
            'savoury_mini_croissants_variants.variant as mini_croissant_variant',
            'savoury_mini_puffs_variants.variant as mini_puff_variant',
            'savoury_mini_ramequins_variants.variant as mini_ramequin_variant',
            'savoury_mini_vols_au_vent_variants.variant as mini_vol_au_vent_variant',
            'savoury_petit_pain_bouchee_variants.variant as petit_pain_bouchee_variant',
            'sweet_sweets.variant as sweet_variant',
            'ice_cream_small_pots_flavors.flavor as ice_cream_small_pot_flavor',
            'ice_cream_pots_flavors.flavor as ice_cream_pot_flavor',
            'ice_cream_frozen_fruits.fruit as ice_cream_frozen_fruit',
            'custom_laboratories as custom_laboratories',
            'custom_name as custom_name',
            'custom_servings as custom_servings',
            'custom_weights as custom_weight',
            'custom_size as custom_size',
            'yul_log_christmas_servings.servings as yul_log_christmas_serving',
            'yul_log_christmas_flavor.flavor as yul_log_christmas_flavor',
            'yul_log_frozen_liters.liter as yul_log_frozen_liter',
            'yul_log_frozen_flavor_one.flavor as yul_log_frozen_flavor_one',
            'yul_log_frozen_flavor_two.flavor as yul_log_frozen_flavor_two',
            'yul_log_frozen_flavor_three.flavor as yul_log_frozen_flavor_three',
            'inscription as inscription',
            'comment as comment',
            'order_items.deleted_at as deleted_at',
            );

            if($user_role_id == 5){
                $orders->whereJsonContains('order_items.laboratory_id', ['1']);
                $orders->whereIn('order_items.status_id', [2]);
                $orders->whereNull('order_items.deleted_at');
            } else if($user_role_id == 6){
                $orders->whereJsonContains('order_items.laboratory_id', ['2']);
                $orders->whereIn('order_items.status_id', [2]);
                $orders->where('order_items.deleted_at', '=', NULL);
            } else if($user_role_id == 7){
                $orders->whereJsonContains('order_items.laboratory_id', ['3']);
                $orders->whereIn('order_items.status_id', [2]);
                $orders->where('order_items.deleted_at', '=', NULL);
            } else if($user_role_id == 8){
                $orders->whereJsonContains('order_items.laboratory_id', ['4']);
                $orders->whereIn('order_items.status_id', [2]);
                $orders->where('order_items.deleted_at', '=', NULL);
            } else if($user_role_id == 9){
                $orders->whereJsonContains('order_items.laboratory_id', ['5']);
                $orders->whereIn('order_items.status_id', [2]);
                $orders->where('order_items.deleted_at', '=', NULL);
            } else if($user_role_id == 10){
                $orders->whereJsonContains('order_items.laboratory_id', ['6']);
                $orders->whereIn('order_items.status_id', [2]);
                $orders->where('order_items.deleted_at', '=', NULL);
            }

            if($request->search_term!="") {

                $orders->where('order_items.id', 'LIKE', "%" . $term . "%")
                        ->orWhere('order_items.order_id', 'LIKE', "%" . $term . "%")
                        ->orWhere('users_a.name', 'LIKE', "%" . $term . "%")
                        ->orWhere('users_b.name', 'LIKE', "%" . $term . "%")
                        ->orWhere('users_b.mobile', 'LIKE', "%" . $term . "%")
                        ->orWhere('order_items.delivery_date', 'LIKE', "%" . $term . "%")
                        ->orWhere('product_categories.name', 'LIKE', "%" . $term . "%")
                        ->orWhere('products.name', 'LIKE', "%" . $term . "%")
                        ->orWhere('custom_name', 'LIKE', "%" . $term . "%")
                        ->orWhere('inscription', 'LIKE', "%" . $term . "%")
                        ->orWhere('savoury_canapes_variants.variant', 'LIKE', "%" . $term . "%")
                        ->orWhere('savoury_mini_croissants_variants.variant', 'LIKE', "%" . $term . "%")
                        ->orWhere('savoury_mini_delices_variants.variant', 'LIKE', "%" . $term . "%")
                        ->orWhere('savoury_mini_puffs_variants.variant', 'LIKE', "%" . $term . "%")
                        ->orWhere('savoury_mini_ramequins_variants.variant', 'LIKE', "%" . $term . "%")
                        ->orWhere('savoury_mini_vols_au_vent_variants.variant', 'LIKE', "%" . $term . "%")
                        ->orWhere('savoury_petit_pain_bouchee_variants.variant', 'LIKE', "%" . $term . "%")
                        ->orWhere('ice_cream_small_pots_flavors.flavor', 'LIKE', "%" . $term . "%")
                        ->orWhere('ice_cream_pots_flavors.flavor', 'LIKE', "%" . $term . "%")
                        ->orWhere('ice_cream_frozen_fruits.fruit', 'LIKE', "%" . $term . "%")
                        ->orWhere('party_loaf_servings.servings', 'LIKE', "%" . $term . "%")
                        ->orWhere('party_loaf_assortment_one.assortment', 'LIKE', "%" . $term . "%")
                        ->orWhere('party_loaf_assortment_two.assortment', 'LIKE', "%" . $term . "%")
                        ->orWhere('party_loaf_assortment_three.assortment', 'LIKE', "%" . $term . "%")
                        ->orWhere('party_loaf_assortment_four.assortment', 'LIKE', "%" . $term . "%")
                        ->orWhere('custom_servings', 'LIKE', "%" . $term . "%")
                        ->orWhere('custom_weights', 'LIKE', "%" . $term . "%")
                        ->orWhere('custom_size', 'LIKE', "%" . $term . "%")
                        ->orWhere('yul_log_christmas_flavor.flavor', 'LIKE', "%" . $term . "%")
                        ->orWhere('yul_log_frozen_flavor_one.flavor', 'LIKE', "%" . $term . "%")
                        ->orWhere('yul_log_frozen_flavor_two.flavor', 'LIKE', "%" . $term . "%")
                        ->orWhere('yul_log_frozen_flavor_three.flavor', 'LIKE', "%" . $term . "%")
                        ->orWhere('inscription', 'LIKE', "%" . $term . "%")
                        ->orWhere('comment', 'LIKE', "%" . $term . "%");
            }

            $orders->where('order_items.deleted_at', '=', NULL);
            $orders->distinct();
            $orders->orderBy('order_items.delivery_date', 'asc');
            $orders  = $orders->whereIn('order_items.status_id', [2])->paginate(10);

        ## START CREATE THE VIEW
        // return view('orders.management', compact('laboratory_staffs', 'staffs','orders','status_orders', 'user_role_id'));
        return view('orders.management-second', compact('laboratory_staffs', 'staffs','orders','status_orders', 'user_role_id'));
        ## END CREATE THE VIEW

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query conditions are not organized correctly. Try the following:

```
if($request->search_term != "") {
    $orders->where(function ($query) use ($term) {
        $query->orWhere('order_items.id', 'LIKE', "%" . $term . "%")
            ->orWhere('order_items.order_id', 'LIKE', "%" . $term . "%")
            // ...
            ->orWhere('comment', 'LIKE', "%" . $term . "%");
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Vlad, works now. Appreciated!